# How to fix incorrect character counting code

Tags: ruby, string

I have a question about mysterious 'e' characters appearing in my `counts` hash.

My initial approach was clunky and inelegant:

```
def letter_count(str)
  counts = {}
  words = str.split(" ")
  words.each do |word|
    letters = word.split("")
    letters.each do |letter| 
      if counts.include?(letter)
        counts[letter] += 1 
      else 
        counts[letter] = 1 
      end 
    end 
  end 
  counts
end
```

This approach worked, but I wanted to make it a little more readable, so I abbreviated it to:

```
def letter_count(str)
  counts = Hash.new(0)
  str.split("").each{|letter| counts[letter] += 1 unless letter == ""}
  counts
end
```

This is where I encountered the issue, and fixed it by using:

```
str.split("").each{|letter| counts[letter] += 1 unless letter == " "} # added a space.
```

I don't understand why empty spaces were being represented by the letter 'e' or being counted at all.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages, and "[mcve]". Concise and clear questions are really important. There was a lot of unnecessary information in your question. In "[mcve]" we need the input data, which is the string you're counting. That helps everyone work on the same problem.

Comment: Could you show us the call to `letter_count` which is giving you this odd behavior? I suspect you're not passing in what you think you are.

Comment: I feel profoundly stupid. I looked at the test cases being provided and sure enough I had simply misread them (there was an 'e' character I didn't see). Thank you all for helping me see this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand why empty spaces were being represented by the letter 'e' or being counted at all.

I can't duplicate the problem:

```
def letter_count(str)
  counts = Hash.new(0)
  str.split("").each{|letter| counts[letter] += 1 unless letter == ""}
  counts
end

letter_count('a cat') # => {"a"=>2, " "=>1, "c"=>1, "t"=>1}
```

"empty spaces"? There's no such thing. A space is not empty; It's considered blank but not empty:

```
' '.empty? # => false
```

Loading the ActiveSupport extension:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/object/blank'
' '.blank? # => true
```

spaces are valid characters, which is why they're being counted. You have to disallow them if you don't want them counted.

For reference, here's how I'd do it:

```
def letter_count(str)
  str.chars.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |l, h| h[l] += 1 }
end

letter_count('a cat') # => {"a"=>2, " "=>1, "c"=>1, "t"=>1}
```

A messier way would be:

```
def letter_count(str)
  str.chars.group_by { |c| c }.map { |char, chars| [char, chars.count] }.to_h
end
```

Breaking that down:

```
def letter_count(str)
  str.chars # => ["a", " ", "c", "a", "t"]
    .group_by { |c| c } # => {"a"=>["a", "a"], " "=>[" "], "c"=>["c"], "t"=>["t"]}
    .map { |char, chars| [char, chars.count] } # => [["a", 2], [" ", 1], ["c", 1], ["t", 1]]
    .to_h # => {"a"=>2, " "=>1, "c"=>1, "t"=>1}
end
```

Comment: Yeah, I misread the test cases. Sorry for wasting your time. I do very much appreciate the distinction you make between empty and blank space--it's helpful both in terms of thinking about data, and in expressing my questions--so not a total loss (for me anyway). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby already has [String#each_char](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-each_char) which you could use.

```
def char_count(string)
    counts = Hash.new(0)

    string.each_char { |char|
        counts[char] += 1
    }

    return counts
end

puts char_count("Basset hounds got long ears").inspect

# {"B"=>1, "a"=>2, "s"=>4, "e"=>2, "t"=>2, " "=>4, "h"=>1,
#  "o"=>3, "u"=>1, "n"=>2, "d"=>1, "g"=>2, "l"=>1, "r"=>1}
```

As for why you're getting the wrong characters, are you sure you're passing in the string you think you are?

Comment: Turned out I was misreading the test cases (the provided strings). You were absolutely right. Thanks for the tip on String#each_char, I'll squirrel that one away for later use.